# Reading Ajax json using Area

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-ajax, http-status-code-500

I'm trying to pull data with the help of Ajax using Asp.net Core Area. Everything seems correct, but I'm getting a 500 error.
Can you help me?

My WriterController class in "area":

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwTrC.png)

WriterController Index:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fwmn1.png)

Layout :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83Rdr.png)

500 error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnU52.png)

Thanks.

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error status code that means something has gone wrong on the website's server. In general Areas are used to separate functionality into groups. The "Views" of that Area should stay with the Area and not to be mixed (as I saw in your case). Furthermore you should use MapAreaControllerRoute (I don't know if u have it). I think is just a configuration problem. Check also the 500 error message, maybe helps you.

Comment: It would be great if you could share your code snippet instead of screenshot. 
Post the code and error as text, not images. Images can't be copied, googled or tested.

Comment: My English is not very good. I couldn't manage to publish it as code. I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem.
I needed to write the return type of the WriterList method in the WriterController class as JSON (not View).

Thanks